# how to append a new line / break to a multiline text box with SendMessage?

Tags: c++, c, winapi

This function works to append text to the end of the window, but I'd like it to append it with a newline/break, appending \n doesn't seem to work.

if the current text in the text box is "cat" and i append "dog" the result will be "catdog" but i want it to be:

"cat
dog"

```
void appendmessage(LPCTSTR newText, HWND hwnd)
{
 SendMessage(hwnd, EM_SETSEL, 0, -1); 
 SendMessage(hwnd, EM_SETSEL, -1, -1); 
 SendMessage(hwnd, EM_REPLACESEL, 0, (LPARAM)TEXT(newText)); 

}
```

Comment: `TEXT` is useless on non-literals. I recommend using wide strings from the start anyway.

Comment: @chris By *useless* you probably meant *wrong*. There is a difference between symbols `newText` and `LnewText`.

Comment: @IInspectable, Well, yes, and being wrong by prepending an L does make it quite useless :p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to append `\r\n`, not just `\n` (since this is Windows, not *nix).